# Getting and setting NumLock state in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, num-lock

Is there a reliable cross-platform way to programmatically get and set the NumLock state in Lazarus / Free Pascal?

I've found `GetKeyState()` in `LclIntf` which seems to work for getting the state (and is apparently cross-platform), but I can't find an equivalent `SetKeyState()`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting leds is rarely part of an userland API, since keyboard leds are hardware, and will require administrator access on most systems.

IIRC I did it once for FreeBSD using the console unit. (which basically sends IOCTLs), Linux is probably similar.

For Windows I found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177674/en-us, but the fact that it is not an universal call, and differs between win9x and winnt says enough.